# How to implement api login in laravel when I already have web login

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have implemented a web logging system in Laravel, there are already users who use this system, but I want those users to also be able to log in to a mobile app so I need to build the login in the API. How could I do it? Could you use the web login?

Comment: I think you may take help of passport to build API and login using API....https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Answer (score 1):

Api login is different from web ones .
In api authetication usually use `token` but web authentication use `session`.

You can define web authentication and parallel define apis with token . Just in each login you should create api token after authenticate user and return this token to user for other request .